# SparkUI - Stages Tab - Size of Input column: With and without repartitionByCassandraReplica

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

So, I have a 16 node cluster where every node has Spark and Cassandra installed with a replication factor of 3 and spark.sql.shuffle.partitions of 96 and Spark-Cassandra-Connector 3.1.0.

I am trying to evaluate the efficiency of repartitionByCassandraReplica().JoinWIthCassandraTable() vs DirectJoin always On in my cluster. More specifically, I am trying to understand the difference in the Input column of Stages tab of SparkUI and the times between these two Joins. Therefore I am doing a join between a dataframe and my cassandra table on partition keys. According to cfstats from every node the Cassandra table is 84.05Gb.

I noticed that when calling repartitionByCassandraReplica().JoinWIthCassandraTable() gives me a different Input size in the Stages tab of SparkUI comparing to the one I get when the DirectJoin is always On. I am aware that these two Joins follow different strategies of determining the Spark partitions.

**Scenario 1 (with PartitionsPerHost=100 -> 1600 spark partitions in total)**

With DirectJoin always On I get **36.9Gb size** in the Input column and it takes **4.1 minutes** for a Join and count. However, with repartitionByCassandraReplica().JoinWIthCassandraTable() on the same data I get **68.9Gb Input size** (almost double) in **3.4 minutes**.

**Scenario 2 (with PartitionsPerHost=2 -> 32 spark partitions in total)**

If I configure repartitionByCassandraReplica to the same number of Spark partitions that I get with DirectJoin always On I still get 68.9Gb but in almost the same amount of time 4.2 minutes (see below pictures).

**Question**

Why does repartitionByCassandraReplica.JoinWIthCassandraTable() take less time in the 1st scenario even if it has a bigger Input size? Is it just because of the data locality from repartitionByCassandraReplica? Weren't they suppose to have the same Input size? Why do they have different Input size column even if they have the same number of Spark partitions?

**In case needed**, below is the code and pictures from stages tab from the two Joins:

**Join with repartitionByCassandraReplica**

```
Encoder<ExperimentForm> ExpEncoder = Encoders.bean(ExperimentForm.class);
Encoder<ExperimentFormOfThree> ExpEncoderofthree = Encoders.bean(ExperimentFormOfThree.class);
Dataset<ExperimentForm> dfexplistoriginal = sp.createDataset(experimentlist, Encoders.STRING()).toDF("experimentid").as(ExpEncoder);
CassandraJavaPairRDD<ExperimentForm, ExperimentFormOfThree> predf = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(dfexplistoriginal.javaRDD()).repartitionByCassandraReplica("mdb","experiment",2,CassandraJavaUtil.someColumns("experimentid"),CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(ExperimentForm.class))).joinWithCassandraTable("mdb","experiment", CassandraJavaUtil.someColumns("experimentid","description","intensity"), CassandraJavaUtil.someColumns("experimentid"), CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo(ExperimentFormOfThree.class), CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(ExperimentForm.class));
Dataset<Row> metlistinitial =sp.createDataset(predf.map(x->x._2).rdd(), ExpEncoderofthree).toDF( "description","experimentid","intensity");
metlistinitial.count();
```

[image]

**Join WITHOUT repartitionByCassandraReplica**

```
Dataset<Row> metlistinitial = sp.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                    {
                        put("keyspace", "mdb");
                        put("table", "experiment");
                    }
                })
.load().select(col("experimentid"), col("description"), col("intensity")).join(dfexplist, "experimentid");
metlistinitial.count();
```

[image]